# Incremental application of Quaternion

Tags: javascript, three.js, game-engine, quaternions, cannon.js

I'm trying to figure out how I might apply a rotation in multiple increments,
to an orientation which is dynamic (i.e. *I cannot use slerp*).

**Details:**
I have an object in a 3D space, whose orientation can be described by quaternion `Q`.
While this object is rotating, it receives periodic updates from another server,
which defines the true orientation.  For example, at time `t1`, the object's orientation
was `Q1`, and received an update that the correct orientation should be `K1`.

I cannot simply replace `Q1` by `K1` because the visual result will not be smooth,
so I would rather correct gradually from `Q1` to `K1` over a sequence of 10 steps.
Also, I cannot use slerp, because `Q1` is not static.  Rather, I would like
to derive an incremental correction, which I call `dK`, until the next server update
arrives.

Right now I derive `dK` in the following way:

1. `delK = K1 * Q1.conjugate()`
2. `dk = delK / 10`

What actually happens at step 2, is that I convert `delK` to an axis+angle representaion,
and then divide the angle by 10.  Then I convert back to a quaternion.

**Question 1:** Is the approach described above mathematically correct?

**Question 2:** I am seeing cases where `dk` is not a small correction and possibly rotating in the opposite direction.  What might cause this.

This is for the implementation of client-side prediction in JavaScript [incheon](http://incheon.gg).

Comment: Use Slerp between current location Q1 and goal rotation K1 with some predefined weight.

Comment: I think you just want an animation to smooth the orientation updates. how about try anime.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace your 10-step approach with a "slerp towards" solution:

```
Q = slerp(Q, Q1, 1 - Math.pow(smoothingRatio, deltaTime)
```

This solution will slerp Q towards Q1 in a frame-rate independent way, and it allows Q1 to be dynamic. After 1 second of interpolation, the remaining fraction of the "distance" to Q1 will be `smoothingRatio`. Read more [here](http://www.rorydriscoll.com/2016/03/07/frame-rate-independent-damping-using-lerp/).

If you have rotations larger than 180 degrees per update, then the closest axis of rotation will be different than on the server. A naive solution would be to send updates more often, or limit the rotational speed of your object(s).

If you were to send angular velocity along with your updates, you could do better client side prediction, and maybe get around the "opposite direction" problem. The idea would be to keep rotating the quaternion along the angular velocity sent in the last update.

The [Quaternion#integrate](https://github.com/schteppe/cannon.js/blob/569730f94a1d9da47967a24fad0323ef7d5b4119/src/math/Quaternion.js#L470) function in Cannon.js implements quaternion integration, which you could use.

```
// Rotate Q along the angular velocity provided in the last update
Q = Q.integrate(angularVelocity, deltaTime, Vec3.ZERO);
```